# mpdf - table column height

Tags: php, css, mpdf

I'm having trouble with mpdf (version 5.7.2) ignoring a fixed (`px`) height on a table column.

Referencing the [MPDF Manual](http://mpdf1.com/manual/) it says that it supports table column heights

both as an html attribute ([HTML attributes section of manual](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=257))

`TD height LENGTH (but not %)`

and as a css style ([Supported CSS section of manual](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=34))

`TD height LENGTH (but not %) (mPDF >= 4.0)`

I have a dynamic number of rows, each row has 10 `<td>` elements. I have a table row like so that spans across 10 columns:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="10" style="width: 720px; height: 232px;">
    <span>Label</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But in the rendered pdf the height is only the size of the content inside it.

Info taken from the [MPDF Limitations](http://mpdf.bpm1.com/index.php?page=Limitations) page:

`Block-level tags (DIV,P etc.) and lists inside table cells are only partially supported (only the 'inline' type CSS styles are applied).`

I tried something like:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="10" style="width: 720px; height: 232px;">
    <div style="height: 232px;">
      <span>Label</span>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But this also didn't yield any results. Does anyone know of why my height on the column is being ignored or knows of a workaround to achieving this?

Comment: Try switching height with width: (height: 232px; width: 720px; and check if the height is still ignored :)

OFFTOPIC: MPDF? Good luck! :)

Comment: @Mr.TK I was thinking about it as well that maybe it's the order of the styles that causes it to be ignored but sadly that isn't whats causing it. Yeah I'm stuck with using mpdf as I can't use any other pdf library :)

Comment: Could You try putting height into <div> only? (no table, tr or td tags). Maybe it's TABLE issue.

Comment: @Mr.TK Thanks for the suggestion. I gave it a try but the height still sticks to only the normal content flow.

Comment: Oh... And try messing with display types :)

Comment: I worked out a solution kind of, instead of using `height` on the table column, I gave it a try with `padding-bottom` and to my surprising it works :) It isn't a solid fix but for now it seems to work nicely

Comment: But You won't be able to insert large content into this td - i mean theoretically ;D 
The height =  content-size + padding-bottom :)

Comment: @Mr.TK In my case it won't be an issue because the pdf in most cases will be used by companies as a print-out :)

Comment: Good ;) So that was a blank form :) - great for U :)

Comment: Height as attribute actually worked for me, but never did as CSS,

Answer (score 1):

A sort of a fix I found out was to use `padding-bottom` instead of `height` on the table column. It gave me the height I needed for the column to be.

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="10" style="width: 720px; padding-bottom: 232px;">
    <span>Label</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```